# How to handle large number of pagination generated in javascript

Tags: javascript, pagination

I am looking for a solution to handle such pagination. All the data are showing dynamically from api. Only 10 items per page are being displayed.

my code to generate pagination

```
pagination: function(total){
    var totalPagination = Math.ceil(total/data_limit);
    var pageNumber = '';

    for(var i=0; i<totalPagination; i++){
        pageNumber += '<li class="active_'+i+'"><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="app.openpage('+i+')">'+ (i+1) +'</a></li>'
    }

    $(pageNumber).insertAfter("#prevCustomerCal_div");
    $("#totalpagenumber").html(total);
    $(".pager li.active_0").addClass("active");
},
```

HTML

```
<ul class="pager">
  <li id="prevCustomerCal_div" class="previous"><a href="javascript:void(0)" id="prevCustomerCal">Previous</a></li>
  <li class="next"><a href="javascript:void(0)" id="nextCustomerCal">Next</a></li>
</ul>
```

[image: pagination]

I do not want to show so many page numbers at once but show few of them and remaining should be hidden. Few page numbers before active page number and few page numbers after active page in visible condition would work.

I can have input box to enter page number also but I way to control that huge page numbers.

There is a active class for active page.
[image]

Comment: How do you know which page are you on?

Comment: via active class on active page number.

Comment: Just checking: so, when `pagination` is executed, you'd look up the active item, fetch the number from it and you now have to generate the page links based on that and total number, right?

Comment: yes something like that would be more helpful

Comment: Something like `prev 1 2 3 ... 269 next` when on page 1, `prev 4 5 6 ... 269 next` when on page 4 could work. Then you only need the current page number and the amount of pages.

Comment: yes but lets not miss the continue integer. For eg: if page 1 is active then page 2,3,4 should be visible and then we could have that three dots and so on.

Comment: maybe this link will help
http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2018/08/07/javascript-pure-pagination-logic-in-vanilla-js-typescript